# error 500 in when installing zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, wampserver

I just installed zend framework on my laptop. When I used wamp server 2.0 to open the index.php file. I received this error
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Can somebody help me to fix that error. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you enable error reporting and show all errors. In your index.php, write this at the top: `ini_set('display_errors','1');error_reporting(-1);`. Also, check your apache logs and if there are errors, post them here. Without any clues, we cannot provide any help.

Answer (score 2):

- Please check the server error log for some clues as to what has happened.
- Check if you have loaded the rewrite module in httpd.conf.

  `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Add this section to your httpd.conf

```
<Directory "{your document root}">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```